# Image capturing via SNAPI.dll API for Symbol barcode scanner DS4208

Tags: c#, barcode-scanner

I want to capture image via SNAPI API from Symbol (currently Zebra) barcode scanner, model DS4208 (we're also using another but compatible models from Zebra). 
Barcode capturing/recognition works pretty well, but looks like **SnapiDLL.SNAPI_SnapShot(hScanner)** call don't work correctly: no **WM_XFERSTATUS** message received at all.
Here is small & simplified code snippet:

```
// Set image format
short[] parms = new short[2] { (short)SnapiParamIds.ImageFileType, (short)SnapiImageTypes.Jpeg };
var retCode = SnapiDLL.SNAPI_SetParameters(parms, 2, _devHandles[0]);
Debug.WriteLine($"SNAPI_SetParameters retCode={retCode}");
Application.DoEvents();
Thread.Sleep(50);

retCode = SnapiDLL.SNAPI_SnapShot(_devHandles[0]);
Debug.WriteLine($"SNAPI_SnapShot retCode={retCode}");
Application.DoEvents();
Thread.Sleep(50);

retCode = SnapiDLL.SNAPI_PullTrigger(_devHandles[0]);
Debug.WriteLine($"SNAPI_PullTrigger retCode={retCode}");
Application.DoEvents();
Thread.Sleep(50);
```

Return codes always 0 (i.e. no error), but no **WM_XFERSTATUS** message received by my message handler.

P.S. C# application from Zebra's SDK which is using CoreScanner driver and OCX, is working fine and able to capture images and video. But I'd like to avoid CoreScanner driver installation for some reasons; for barcode scanning small and simple SNAPI.dll works pretty fine, and I expect to get it work for image capturing too - probably, I'm doing something wrong...

P.P.S. Guys, please **DO NOT COMMENT** if you have **NO EXPERIENCE WORKING WITH SYMBOL BARCODE SCANNERS & SNAPI**, and **CAN NOT PROVIDE** a working snippet!

Comment: Use the vendor driver and not the standard Microsoft driver.  Microsoft standard drive only implements standard features and many hardware manufacturers on;y use a small portion of the standard interfaces.

Comment: @jdweng, question is not about using "standard or non-standard driver". By the way, SNAPI.dll - it's abbreviation of "Symbol Native Application Programming Interface" (so it's vendor standard driver and API). And I'm curious why it's not working as it supposed to be, according to API documentation: https://www.labviewforum.de/attachment.php?aid=50061

Comment: Those DoEvents() calls look very unhealthy, they suggest you made it too simple and didn't create a Winforms or WPF app.  The kind that have a dispatcher loop that ensures you can correctly receive a WM_ message.  DoEvents() can't work, it takes too much time to make the snapshot.  And of course the message handler you wrote is significant to diagnose any "it doesn't work" kind of problem.

Comment: @Hans-Passant, your comment is absolutely irrelevant. Events handling is **working fine** in the app, and I receiving (and handling) all messages from SNAPI dll. My issue not with the Windows messages handling or "bad code".

Comment: Who makes this SNAPI?  You should be asking them for Tech Support not the general purpose site such as SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After contacting Zebra tech support (they are successors of Symbol/Motorola barcode scanner business), I figured out that the imaging/video functionality is broken in SNAPI.dll for the x64 OSes (but most of the rest API calls are working properly). Unfortunately, SNAPI isn't supported by Zebra anymore, and I should use Zebra's CoreScanner API. The good news is: this API is working fine, as it supposed to be. Not a very good news: I should use additional installation package from Zebra.